# Get Value of multiple inputs inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey Guys i got a table which looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="test1" placeholder="Test1">
      <input type="text" name="test2" placeholder="Test2">
      <input type="text" name="test3" placeholder="Test3">
      <input type="text" name="test4" placeholder="Test4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="test1" placeholder="Test4">
      <input type="text" name="test2" placeholder="Test5">
      <input type="text" name="test3" placeholder="Test6">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="test1" placeholder="Test7">
      <input type="text" name="test2" placeholder="Test8">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I want to get all values of the Inputs inside the last `td` and that for each table row. Best would if I could store each value inside a string and delimit the values by an ";" and after that store this string inside an array. So in this specific case there would be 3 strings with values. I use JavaScript and Jquery and would really appreciate some help.

so yeah i already tried to use a foreach condition for each tr but that didnt worked out.

my JS code looked something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var valueArray[];
  $("button").click(function(event) {
   $("tr").each(function(index) {
     var valueString;
   $("td input").each(function(){
     valueString += this.value;
    });
  valueArray.push(valueString);
  });
 });
});
```

LAST EDIT:

So guys i got a solution now thanks to Alen i just had to do a bit of configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ressultArray = [];
  $("button").click(function(event) {
    var trResult = '';
    $('table').find('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('td input').each(function() {
        if (trResult.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1)
          trResult += $(this).val() + ';';
      });
      var result = trResult.slice(0, -1);
      console.log(result);
      console.log(trResult);
      ressultArray.push(result);
      trResult = '';
    });
    console.log(ressultArray);
  });
});
```

At the Moment i'm deleting the last semicolon cause i'm working further with this array to evualate the different values. 
there is still room for improvement but i just wanted something to get going. Thanks to all.

here a plunker to test:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GMOgDA9dB0Y5Eosu0hVR?p=preview

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share whatever JS attempts you have written?

Comment: Looks like you ask someone to write code for you. It's not how SO works. Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question appropriately

Comment: You really need to learn how to use SO as @Andersson says.

Comment: The problem is that i already tried things but they didnt worked out and they wouldnt be any better if i improve them. So I would like a fresh start for it

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried.

Comment: so yeah i did so please put the question back online. I think that could help others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop throw each td in rows. 
Here is an example

```
$('table').find('tr').each(funtion(){
var trResult= '';
$(this).find('td').each(function()
{
IF(trResult.indexOf($(this).val()) ===-1)
trResult += $(this).val() +';';
});
});
```

This is writen in my mobile so sorry for bad formating

Comment: Hey @Alen.Toma thanks that looks pretty similar to mine but i will try it and tell you if it helps. :)

Comment: But could you help me and say what the if condition there is for.

Comment: the if confition is so that you dont add the same value twice, so you could not have test1;test1